# What does {1:X} mean in C#?

Tags: c#

I don't quite get what {1:X} is in this piece of code:

```
    ushort secretKey = 0x0088; // The cyphering key.
    char character = 'A';      // The initial key to be cyphered.
    Console.WriteLine("Initial symbol: {0}, its code in the symbols' table: {1:X}", character, (byte)character);
```

I mean, I realize that {0:X} means a lowercase hexadecimal, but does that mean that {1:X} is a decimal? Thanks for explaining.

Comment: No, it means it is the second argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known as composite formatting. `1` means second argument and `X` means hexadecimal. [Here is the list.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: if A is 0x0041, then the second argument is 0041 in my case, right? and that is why I get 41 in the console? and if I write {0:X}, will I get 0x0041?

Comment: @Dariushka No, if you want a 2 zero leading hex-number with 2 places, you need to use `{0:X4}`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-hexadecimal-x-format-specifier

Comment: @Dariushka if the answer is helpful for you, you can click the tick on the left side.